# Is it possible to echo an error if the selected date is also inside the database

Tags: php, date, datepicker

Is it possible to echo an error if the selected date is also inside the database?

Here is the datepicker http://postimg.org/image/g3lhz4o5l/

and this is the database http://postimg.org/image/oy4vtfhcz/

---

here is my current code

```
$disabled_date = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar");

if($_POST['date'] === $disabled_date){                          
    echo 'Error!';
} else {
echo 'OK! :)'; 
}
```

but it doesnt echo the error. I dont know were and how should i compare this two values

---

Thank you for all the answers.. after reading all of your comments I manage to make it work.. Here is the working code

```
    function disabled_dates($date){
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(calendar_id) FROM calendar WHERE disabled_date = '$date'"),0) == 1)? true : false;
}

if(disabled_dates($_POST['date']) === true){
    echo 'Error!';
} else {
    echo 'Date accepted!';
}
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: var_dump($disabled_date); before if condition and post the values you get as $disabled_date

Comment: Tried adding var_dump($disabled_date); in between mysql_query and if statement but getting 'resource(26) of type (mysql result) Resource id #26' error

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the date using php and pass it to your model if you use MVC architecture.
Then you need to do query for check if there is the date in the database.

You can return true or false when date is there and not there accordingly.
Then print the error message according to the return value.

Please put the code you have tried.Otherwise it is difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: Sorry but Im new to web development.. can u post sample codes.. im trying to think how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Please add comment your $disabled_date values you get.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how exactly you want to achieve this. If you first select the date from the datepicker and it goes into a text box, you fill the rest of the form and then press a button to submit this data, of course you can get the value from the text box via $_POST and then use it when connecting to your Database to compare it to the date string in the Database.

Comment: selecting in the datepicker first then I want to compare if it has a same value in the database then output error. Thanks for reply :)